# Can a mortgage payment date be changed?

Tags: mortgage

Can a mortgage payment date be changed? When we closed on our home over 2 years ago, our attorney told us we could call up the lender and they could change our due date to later in the month. Our due date is always the 1st of the mo, with a grace period until the 16th however, my husband gets paid at the end of the month. We always pay within the 30days however its always after the 16th, therefore we are charged a $75 late fee every month and they are MOUNTING! Any suggestions? Can it in fact be changed and if so, how do we go about it?

Comment: Have you called the lender to ask?

Comment: Related question about mortgage due dates: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2102/mortgage-due-date-versus-late-payment-penalty-can-the-loan-company-call-me-dail

Comment: It depends on lender but usually you can only change it so many times. Also, if you are like some people you have to split your paychecks in half. So you will have to hold money from first paycheck and combine with second paycheck to pay mortgage. It's fairly typical.

Answer (score 21):

It sounds like you have zero in your savings/emergency fund. You cannot afford this house. If in fact, you are living paycheck to paycheck, it only takes one minor expense to put you into late payments. A broken transmission, a new set of tires. Anything. If he is getting paid at month end and you can't pay the mortgage due on the 1st, then you are not just living hand to mouth, but you are always behind.

In effect, you'd like 30 days grace, to catch the next paycheck.

You say your husband is paid then, do you work? You need to talk about finding extra income. You see, the frugal route may work for a time, but it's easier to get some kind of part time work and pull in a few hundred dollars a weekend than to keep cutting expenses.

Answer (score 13):

It sounds like you're behind on a payment.  Is that the case?

Perhaps you could be "ahead" on a payment.  If your payment is on the 1st, that's only a few days after your husband gets paid (assuming the last Friday of the month, this would mean the earliest he would get paid is around the 25th).  Perhaps you made your first payment before it was due, and your next payment (after he was paid again was on that last Friday), to the bank that payment would be for the first payment; you technically made an extra payment by paying early.

Can't you just change the date you send/draw the payment?  After all, it's generally just another 5 or 6 days from pay day until the first of the month.

In other words it sounds like you should be paying your April mortgage payment with your March paycheck.

Answer (score 7):

Read your mortgage contract, it may be possible. You may be able to arrange for direct deposit of payments directly from your check.

Right now, you're accumulating negative credit report items every month, which means that you're now considered a "bad" borrower. You need to stop spending money, get ahead on your payments for 3-4 months and then ask.

If you have a tax refund coming, this is a great place to use it.

Comment: If anyone's budget is so tight they cannot keep current, they should look closely at their withholdings and submit a new W4. This couple is a clear case where they can better use the money and not lend it to Uncle Sam each year.